# Unit tests with StaticMessageSource and using a null locale

Tags: spring, unit-testing

I'm unit testing a service which uses a messageSource and passing in a [staticMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/StaticMessageSource.html) to use as a mock object. staticMessageSource allows the programmatic creation of messages using addMessage(String code, Locale locale, String msg).
Locale is a required parameter here (it cannot be null). However I use a null locale for messages that come from the real messageSource, meaning I can't use staticMessageSource as a mock message source. Can anyone think of a way around this? I don't want to have to set a locale for all my messages.

Comment: Subclass the Locale and that returns null for everything or whatever you want it to return.

Comment: just tried that, but Locale is final and can't be sub-classed

Answer (score 2):

You could think about rolling your own MessageSource implementation. The interface just exposes three methods and implementing an `addMessage` method which stores your preresolved messages in a map should be simple enough.